# How can I one-hot encode my dataset with several categorical variables in R?

Tags: r, analytics, data-science, one-hot-encoding

Does anyone know how I can better clean up this data so I can run a logistic regression on it?

I am trying to one-hot encode the variables with multiple categories like race, workclass, etc (as shown in the sample dataset below), but not sure how to do so.

I was planning to change the income to 1 and 0 since there is only 2 categories but I cannot do the same for the rest.

My current plan is to run a logistic regression with all the listed variables:

```
data <- read.csv("adult_income.csv")
mylogit <- glm(formula = income ~ age + workclass + educaitonal-num + 
                   martial status + occupation + race + gender + 
                   capital-gain + capital-loss + hours-per-week + 
                   native-country, data = data, family = "binomial")
```

Sample dataset:
[image: 1]

I am still fairly new to R so I apologize for any rookie mistake!

Comment: My goal is to create a logit model that reflects the probability of an individual's income to be above or below 50k, given their age, occupation, workclass, etc.

Comment: I believe that matrix.model()  is what you want.  I'm just not positive if it uses one hot encoding for categorical variables.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, @peterpra! It would be better if you could post your data via `dput(head(df))` into the original question or create mock data. [See here for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: You may find the below link useful: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable)

Comment: You may find this link useful: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952706/generate-a-dummy-variable)

Answer (score 2):

R very nicely one hot encodes categorical variables internally when you wrap the variable in the as.factor() function.
Question was answered btw already in  [categorical variable in logistic regression in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121325/categorical-variable-in-logistic-regression-in-r)

Answer (score 2):

*Updated 2023-11-15:*

With `data.table` and `mltools`:

```
df <- as.data.table(df)
df_oh <- one_hot(df)
```

#### Result & Explanation

```
> head(df_oh)
   age education_level marital_status_Divorced marital_status_Married marital_status_Never marital_status_Widowed occupation_Admin occupation_Banking occupation_Farming occupation_Fishing occupation_Poledancing gender_Man gender_Unicorn gender_Woman    hours income_<=50K income_>50K
1:  85              15                       0                      0                    1                      0                0                  0                  0                  0                      1          0              1            0 39.40777            0           1
2:  56               6                       0                      0                    1                      0                0                  0                  0                  0                      1          1              0            0 40.98112            1           0
3:  18               1                       0                      0                    1                      0                0                  0                  0                  0                      1          0              0            1 40.53241            0           1
4:  51               9                       0                      1                    0                      0                0                  1                  0                  0                      0          1              0            0 39.90954            1           0
5:  60               7                       0                      0                    1                      0                0                  0                  0                  0                      1          1              0            0 40.15649            0           1
6:  31               7                       1                      0                    0                      0                1                  0                  0                  0                      0          0              1            0 39.26269            0           1
```

What `one_hot()` is doing is taking all factor variables (i.e., not numeric, not character, etc.) of a data table and one-hotting them. It needs a data table (and not, say, a data frame), because data tables provide some features/concepts that help with flexibility and speed.

If you check the documentation under `?one_hot` you will see that the function can also treat `NA`s pretty nicely (if this is a concern in your data).

If you have any questions, please feel free to add a comment.

#### Reproduction

```
# Load libraries
library(data.table)
library(mltools)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(1)

# Create mock data frame
df <- data.frame(
    age = sample(18:85, 50, replace = TRUE),
    education_level = sample(1:15, 50, replace = TRUE),
    marital_status = factor(sample(c("Never", "Married", "Divorced", "Widowed"), 50, replace = TRUE)),
    occupation = factor(sample(c("Admin", "Farming", "Poledancing", "Fishing", "Banking"), 50, replace = TRUE)),
    gender = factor(sample(c("Man", "Woman", "Unicorn"), 50, replace = TRUE)),
    hours = rnorm(50, 40, 1),
    income = factor(sample(c("<=50K", ">50K"), 50, replace = TRUE))
)
```

##### Resulting in:

```
   age education_level marital_status  occupation  gender    hours income
1:  85              15          Never Poledancing Unicorn 39.40777   >50K
2:  56               6          Never Poledancing     Man 40.98112  <=50K
3:  18               1          Never Poledancing   Woman 40.53241   >50K
4:  51               9        Married     Banking     Man 39.90954  <=50K
5:  60               7          Never Poledancing     Man 40.15649   >50K
6:  31               7       Divorced       Admin Unicorn 39.26269   >50K
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the same result of your example. The categorical columns are didn't change after applying `one_hot` function. Did the function change it behaviour? @Roman

Comment: @falamiw Not sure what happened here, but I didn't have any factor variables in the code. Updated & thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Install the library **dummies**

Example:

```
library(dummies)
# example data 
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:4, year = 1991:1994)
df1 <- cbind(df1, dummy(df1$year, sep = "_"))
```

This will generate the dummy variables as below:

```
df1
#   id year df1_1991 df1_1992 df1_1993 df1_1994
# 1  1 1991        1        0        0        0
# 2  2 1992        0        1        0        0
# 3  3 1993        0        0        1        0
# 4  4 1994        0        0        0        1
```